# NativeScript Setup Issue with pip install six

Tags: python, macos, terminal, nativescript, homebrew

I am going through the NativeScript Advanced Setup (https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x) on my new Macbook Pro and have hit a snag on step 3.6.

When I attempt to run pip install six, I get pip: command not found.

Because this is running on Homebrew, I want to make sure that I am installing pip in the correct way for NativeScript mobile development.

I have gone through this setup many times and haven't run into this before.  The instructions change regularly however and the hardware and software environments are always different.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Orion.

Comment: Have you installed Python?

Comment: Yes, I've just installed Python 3.7.4 for macosx, but I still get pip: command not found.